# What happened to Danaerys' first pregnancy?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones, I don't quite get the story about Danaerys being pregnant the first time. In Season One, King Robert is informed that Daenerys is pregnant and raises the demand that both she, her unborn child, and her brother Viserys be assassinated as royal policy. This causes Eddard Stark to resign as Hand of the King and return to Winterfell. So, my question is:

1. How (or by whom) did Danaerys get pregnant? Much later in the series she mentions that she has "been raped". Is that a reference to this pregnancy?
2. What became of the pregnancy? Obviously by the time she flees to the Dothraki she is no longer pregnant. So, was she just not actually pregnant or all (Possibility A), or the pregnancy terminated in a miscarraige (Possibility B), or did she have the baby and it got situated somewhere else (Possibility C)?

Comment: Drogo is the father, it's a major plot point for season 1.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Ok, maybe I have my timeline mixed up. I thought Robert ordered the assassination before the Targaryans met with the Dothraki. If he ordered it AFTER she had become queen to the Dothraki, then what? Robert is ordering the assassination of a foreign queen??? That makes no sense.

Comment: The assassination order was a pre-emptive measure (been a while since I've watched it but I know they discuss it after Dany's wedding before her pregnancy). They see the Targaryen's are amassing an army and could start reproducing. Robert is still referred to as Usurper by some, if they decide to cross the Narrow Sea then there will be another was in the Seven Kingdoms with some of them supporting the Targaryens.

Comment: Assassinations of kings and queens is about half the plot of the first season/book. Whether it “makes sense” or not is a separate question

Answer (score 5):

Drogo is the father. The child is stillborn. https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Daenerys_Targaryen

> According to Duur, the child is stillborn and deformed, with leathery scaled skin, wings and a stomach filled with grave-worms. Duur saves Drogo's life, but leaves him in a vegetative state. Duur admits she did this deliberately in revenge for the sacking of her village. The ritual that saved Drogo drew its power from the death of Daenerys's son, causing her child's stillbirth and monstrous appearance. Daenerys is distraught.

Her later reference to a rape, *could* be a reference to Drogo's actions on their wedding night (https://news.sky.com/story/game-of-thrones-emilia-clarkes-rape-scene-was-degrading-says-co-star-nikolaj-coster-waldau-12103072) but that isn't what necessarily lead to her pregnancy.

Comment: I know all about Drogo. I thought there had been a different pregnancy BEFORE she went to the Dothraki. Apparently I have my timelines mixed up.